# What is the relationship between the distance of a current carrying wire and a dipole magnet's magnetic field strength?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

For school, I'm doing this experiment where I measure the change in magnetic field strength, between a magnet and a current-carrying wire as a function of the distance. Online after doing some reading, I found this inverse square law thing more specifically Biot–Savart law. I was wondering if this applies to this experiment, or if there is no clear relationship such as the inverse square law?

Comment: "I measure the change in magnetic field strength, between a magnet and a current-carrying wire as a function of the distance" (a) Does this mean that you measure the resultant field due to the magnet and the wire? (b) a function of what distance? (c) How is the wire orientated  in relation to the magnet? (d) how are you measuring the field strength?

Comment: My bad for the poor phrasing of the question. For this experiment, there is a magnet and a current-carrying copper wire loop and I measure the force on this wire loop by measuring the weight. I just wanted to know if there is a clear relationship between the change in weight and how far away the magnet is.